How to take a week number, convert it to a date, add a number of days and convert back to a week number?
On my team, we have to constantly manually change week numbers. Since its a report done once a week where we have to use the same template. I wanted to figure out a way where we just change 1 cell to this current week and then a formula changes all the rest to the next week in a series of weeks.  I am not allowed to always have a weeknumber() formula in the first week cell remain as a formula bc it would change all the data if we were to open the file at a later date.
So I did some research and found this site: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/discussions/excelgeneral/convert-week-of-the-year-into-a-date/3571944
and I came up with a bit of a long formula that works.  I would like to know if there is a simpler way to have these.
example: A1: 202448
the formula i have come up with to convert the week number to a date + 7 days & then convert back is:
=TEXT((DATE(LEFT(A1,4),1,-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(LEFT(A1,4),1,1))+RIGHT(A1,2)*7)+7,"YYYY")&TEXT(WEEKNUM((DATE(LEFT(A1,4),1,-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(LEFT(A1,4),1,1))+RIGHT(A1,2)*7)+7,1),"00")

results in 202449
Is there as simpler way to do this?

would =IF(--RIGHT(A1,2)>=WEEKNUM(DATE(--LEFT(A1,4),12,31)),--(LEFT(A1,4)+1&"01"),A1+1) suit your needs?

@ScottCraner i tested your formula - sadly it populates a week 53, this year would need it to go from 52 to then week 1 of next year

But there is 53 weeks this year...=WEEKENUM("2024-12-31") returns 53.  If you always assume 52 to be the max, eventually week 1 will be in the middle of December.  There are 365 days in a year 365/7 has a remainder of 1, on Leap years the remainder is 2.

but if you do not care about that: =IF(--RIGHT(A1,2)>=52,--(LEFT(A1,4)+1&"01"),A1+1)

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-weeknum-function-convert-week-number-date/

Will you always be adding 7 days?

@RonRosenfeld it will be adding 7days for each column next to it for 5 weeks.

@CorlissExcelling It sure would have been helpful had you included your proposed output in your question. But see my edited answer for a solution. And if that's not what you need, edit your question to provide the specifics.

If you are always adding one week (7 days) then the following should work:It makes use of the fact that when using the WEEKNUM function, the first week always starts with Jan 1 and will automatically adjust for the frequently shortened first week.
Edit: To show results in six adjacent columns (you change the Sequence function for the number of columns)
=LET(
    d, A1,
    yr, LEFT(d, 4),
    wn, RIGHT(d, 2) + SEQUENCE(,6,0),
    _d1, DATE(yr, 1, wn * 7),
    YEAR(_d1) * 100 + WEEKNUM(_d1)
)


Note that

the initial yyyyww is in A1
the formula is in B1
the results of that formula Spill to the right

Also note that because the first week of 2025 is a "short week", it does not appear.
Instead of using a week numbering system implied by use of Excels WEEKNUM function, you could use the more commonly used business/financial system related to ISO dates.
In that system, the first week of a "year" always begins on a Monday, and always includes the first Thursday of a year. In that system, a year might have 52 or 53 weeks, but a week will always have seven days.
To adapt the above formula to be ISO weeknumbering compliant, you merely have to find the first Thursday of the year. The preceding Monday will be the start of Week 01
=LET(
    d, A1,
    yr, LEFT(d, 4),
    wn, RIGHT(d, 2) + SEQUENCE(, 5),
    firstThursday, DATE(yr, 1, 8) - WEEKDAY(DATE(yr, 1, 8), 15),
    _week1, firstThursday - 4,
    _d1, _week1 + wn * 7,
    YEAR(_d1) * 100 + ISOWEEKNUM(_d1)
)

And then no "short weeks" will be excluded. However, 202501 will start on Monday December 30, 2024

